# error retrieving current directory: getcwd in Docker container

Tags: php, docker

I'm running the 'php:7.4-fpm' container to server a laravel application. When I tried to ssh into the container, I got the following error:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

This happened suddenly, I'm working on this project for almost 3 months and had never faced this scenario. 
My host machine is a **mac, catalina (version 10.15.3)**

I can run other commands like php/ php artisan etc but its taking too long to respond and also any command related to directories like getcwd/pwd etc are not working.

Why does this happen?

It works fine after restarting the containers but is there permantent solution?

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] explaining how you built the image and exactly what commands you're running?

Comment: Steps to reproduce:

docker-compose exec php-fpm bash

Often I get the error, often I don't. Today, this error occurred around 40% of the time.

Docker image, 
I'm using the official php:7.4-fpm image. Installed depended libraries for laravel (like mbstring,pdo mysql etc) & installing composer.

And in the compose file, 


just forwarding a port. 

[Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/thearyanahmed/b1f99234632650776148d917fa8ba503)

Answer (score 7):

Just encountered same issue. For me rootcause was, that the current folder I'm in was deleted. So solution - check if current folder exists, and cd to an existing one, if current is deleted.

Comment: In my case it was even more intriguing, as the directory was deleted and recreated with the same name, so "cd-ing to the parent and back to the original" was the solution.

Comment: A deleted directory that was recreated afterwards with the same name was also the cause in my case. Good hint! Restarting the docker container (`docker stop [containername]` / `docker start [containername]') did the trick for me.